# How to rig unconnected vertices

Tags: mesh, rigging

i downloaded a .obj from the internet, and some parts of it are unconnected, and when i try to rig it to animate, i can't move that unconnected parts with the armatures, moving only a part of the mesh
[image]

[image]

[image]

also, even if they are unconnected vertices, they are all part of the same mesh, i can't find a way to send the blend file here, so if needed i can upload it in some site and send the link or something like that.

Comment: Yes please share the file, use the following site or another one: https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: ok, here it is: https://pasteall.org/blend/cc0240a6ce0e40599f59f60feb4240d9

Answer (score 0):

If you're talking for example about this part, just assign it to the vertex group that it is supposed to be part of, i.e. the bone called by the name of the bone, which is Perna.r:

[image]